# Dropdown List - Display Value Instead of Text

Tags: javascript, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I am using a Dropdown List to replace a Combo Box.  For the dropdown text, I am concatenating the two columns and displaying them as one, which works fine.  When they select a column, I need to display the selected VALUE rather than the selected TEXT, but I still need the text to display as the selectable options.

Is there an easy way to do this?  Or alternatively how could I make a multi-column dropdown list and use one column as the selected text?

In my dropdown list, I have:

```
Value  Text
1      Option One
2      Option Two
3      Option Three
```

When I select 'Option One', I need the dropdown text display to be '1'.  Hope that clarifies things enough.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to display the value? Do you have some HTML or Javascript to show us?

Comment: The value needs to display as the selected item of the dropdown list.  i.e. if the selected item text is 'Joe' and the value is '1', the dropdown list displays '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it by using an infragistics webDropDown with the client-side event:

```
    function webDropDown_SelectionChanging(sender, e) {
        e.get_value()[0].set_text(e.get_value()[0].get_value());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically adding data to your ComboBox, this can be achieved by assigning a value to each record that is added. This means at runtime you can then display the value `Dim string as String = ComboBox1.SelectedValue` whilst having the ComboBox display the text in the dropdown.

Comment: I am replacing the combo box with a dropdown list, so the combo box will no longer be used.